# How to create section breaks type next page in docx by apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx

I want to create different sections in docx file that each sections have different page numbers format (one section has 1,2,3... page number format and another section has a,b,c,... page number format etc.). And I want to check "Different First Page" option for each sections like picture below:
[image: Different First Page]

Note: I tried this code but they create page breakes not section breaks:

```
....
XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();
run.addBreak(BreakType.PAGE);
....
```

another code:

```
paragraph = document.createParagraph();
paragraph.setPageBreak(true);
```

both of this code create page breaks not section breaks.

section breaks is like this and I want this:
[image: section breaks]

and page breaks are like this and I don't want it:
[image: page breaks]

First, how can I create section breaks?
Second, How can I set different page number formats?
Third, How can I set "Different First Page" option for each section?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

POI does not currently (as of POI 3.17) support sections in the high level interface. You will have to understand the underlying XML and use the CT classes to construct your sections. Here is a high level fly by. For all sections except the last section in a document, the `<sectPr>` element is stored in the last paragraph of the section. For the last section in a document, the `<sectPr>` element is the last child element of the `<body>` element. You are going to have to code this yourself though. Maybe you can contribute a patch to the project.

Answer (score 2):

Based on jmarkmurphy's answer, I implemented something that works for me:

```
CTBody body = document.getDocument().getBody();
CTSectPr sectPr = body.getSectPr();
if (sectPr != null) {
  XWPFParagraph lastParagraph = document.createParagraph();
  lastParagraph.getCTP().addNewPPr().setSectPr(sectPr);
  body.unsetSectPr();
}
document.createParagraph().setPageBreak(true);
```